# How to avoid Superdevmode from GWT

Tags: gwt

I once run the superdev mode ,

Now whenever i try to run Classic mode , It keeps on running app in superdevmode.

In my run configuration , under GWT Tab, Classic Devleopment Mode is selected

Under Arguments tab , I dont see any superdev command

I removed xsiframe command from my gwt.xml file.

BUT , Its still in superdev mode and in my browser it keeps on showing Superdev (GWT Compile option)  at the bottom , and my app not showing anything

http://screencast.com/t/QEood7MXMR4P

Any suggestion how to clear this thing , and avoid this superdev mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SuperDevMode puts things in your war folder.
Clean up the war folder by removing everything that was generated, and not put there by you.

Comment: There should be a complete folder with files with a name *.nocache.js , clear.cache.gif ? You should delete that entire dir.